# Taking two lists and comparing for similarities

Tags: python, list

I have two lists shown below:

```
sq = [['welcome'], ['we', 'are'], ['the', 'champions']]
sl = [['we', 'are', 'rainbow', 'while', 'to', 'and', 'do', 'welcome', 'while', 'cant', 'did'], ['are', 'time', 'to', 'do', 'the', 'champions', 'while', 'am']]
```

I need to create a for loop that will see how many elements from sq are contained within a sublist from sl. If one of the words within sq is contained within sl, it'll add a 1 as a match, and 0 if it isn't.

So as an example from the lists above, we take the first sublist from sl, which is:

```
['we', 'are', 'rainbow', 'while', 'to', 'and', 'do', 'welcome', 'while', 'cant', 'did']
```

and compare it to the qs list to see if anything from qs is contained in the sublist. The outcome should been a list like this:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

there are 11 words in the first sublist, and this is how i want the matches to show within a list. I need to do this for each sublist within sl. Beneath is my current code which is way off.

```
testList = []
testlistnew =[]
for k in sl:
    if k not in testlistnew:
        testlistnew[k] = 0
    if k in sq:
        testList[k] = 1
    else:
        testList[k] = 0
```

FYI, this should be the output for the entirety of comparing sq with sl:

```
matches = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I assume deleting the entire body of your question was accidental.  If you want to shorten your question by all means do but I think you cut it a bit too short :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. `sum` is just flattening your nested list here.

```
sq = [['welcome'], ['we', 'are'], ['the', 'champions']]
sl = [['we', 'are', 'rainbow', 'while', 'to', 'and', 'do', 'welcome', 'while', 'cant', 'did'], ['are', 'time', 'to', 'do', 'the', 'champions', 'while', 'am']]

_flat = sum(sq, [])
test = []

for i, nested_list in enumerate(sl):
    test.append([])
    for item in nested_list:
        test[i].append(1 if item in _flat else 0)
print(test)
```

Forloop probably aids more in understanding, but this can be done more succinctly using a list comprehension. Or, see the comment.

```
sq = [['welcome'], ['we', 'are'], ['the', 'champions']]
sl = [['we', 'are', 'rainbow', 'while', 'to', 'and', 'do', 'welcome', 'while', 'cant', 'did'], ['are', 'time', 'to', 'do', 'the', 'champions', 'while', 'am']]
_flat = sum(sq, [])
test = [[1 if item in _flat else 0 for item in nl] for nl in sl]
```

Comment: you could just use `test[-1].append(...)` to save the trouble of needing enumerate, actually the whole thing could be put into nested list comprehension to save all the appending.

Comment: `test = [ [int(item in _flat) for item in nested_list] for nested_list in sl]`

Answer (score 1):

Another option.

Notes:

- I prefer list comprehensions to for loops.
- I put all of data to be matched in a `set` to speed lookup.

```
from pprint import pprint

# Test data
sq = [['welcome'], ['we', 'are'], ['the', 'champions']]
sl = [['we', 'are', 'rainbow', 'while', 'to', 'and', 'do', 'welcome', 'while', 'cant', 'did'], ['are', 'time', 'to', 'do', 'the', 'champions', 'while', 'am']]

# Create result
sq_set = set(sq_str for sq_item in sq for sq_str in sq_item)
result =  [
    [
        int(sl_str in sq_set)
        for sl_str in sl_item
    ]
    for sl_item in sl
]

# Display result
pprint (result)
```